# Add CSS when clicking Button with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to add a css class with javascript when i click the 'Reservieren' Button. I have found many answers about this on google but I was not able to solve the problem with the answers.

my js.js code:

```js
function platzReservieren() {
  var court1 = document.getElementById('court1');
  if (court1_ausgewaehlt === true) {
    court1.classList.add('canvas-reservated');
  }
}

function leftClickOnCourt1() {
var court1 = document.getElementById('court1');
if(court1.classList.contains('canvas-reservated')){
    court1_reserviert = true;
}
var context = court1.getContext('2d');
if(court1_reserviert !== true){
    if (court1_ausgewaehlt === false) {
        court1.classList.add('canvas-selected');
        court1_ausgewaehlt = true;
    } else if (court1_ausgewaehlt === true) {
        court1.classList.remove('canvas-selected');
        court1_ausgewaehlt = false;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-secondary " style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 0 0 0;" type="submit" name="reservieren" onclick="platzReservieren()" value="Reservieren">Reservieren</button>

<div class="row" id="courts">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 1</h3>
            <canvas id="court1" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt1()"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 2</h3>
            <canvas id="court2" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt2()"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 3</h3>
            <canvas id="court3" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt3()"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, you're adding the class correctly, so what's happening? If it's not getting added, it's because your condition is evaluating to false.

Comment: Where did you get `court1_ausgewaehlt`?

Comment: court1_ausgewahlt is setted to true when the user clicks on the court1 element.

Comment: That seems quite essential to your question. So better put that code in your question.

Comment: My condition retrieves true back, i don't know why my css isn't added

Comment: I updated your code in a snippet but its missing few parts. Can you please add missing values?

Comment: A suggestion, instead of adding `onclick` on markup, if you can change it, remove it and use `.addEventListener` to add event. This way, you do not need to fetch the button again. Its a part of your context

Comment: I added the missing code where court1_ausgewaehlt is setted to true when the user clicks on the canvas element

Comment: @Paphill please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a snippet using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```js
function platzReservieren() {
  var court1 = document.querySelector('button');
  if (court1) {
    court1.classList.add('canvas-reservated');
  }
}
```

```css
.canvas-reservated {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-secondary " style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 0 0 0;" type="submit" name="reservieren" onclick="platzReservieren()" value="Reservieren">Reservieren</button>
```

Comment: I missed to add the code where the element with the id="court1" is defined. I will add this right now

Comment: @Paphill don't add only code, add an executable code snippet, it would be helpful for someone to give answers correctly & timely.

Comment: I don't know how to add a snippet i don't use stackoverflow often

Comment: @Paphill How to set [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you do this you will get your answers easily & it also saves time of someone trying to give you answers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#reservation');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.classList.toggle('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="reservation" class="btn btn-secondary" style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 0 0 0;" type="submit" name="reservieren" value="Reservieren">Reservieren</button>
```

This is a little other approach compared to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this `id="court1"` to the target element. You were trying to access an element that is not defined

```js
function platzReservieren() {
  var court1_ausgewaehlt = true
    var court1 = document.getElementById('court1');
    if (court1_ausgewaehlt === true) {
        court1.classList.add('canvas-reservated');
    }
}
```

```css
.canvas-reservated{
color:red
}
```

```html
<button id="court1" class="btn btn-secondary " style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 0 0 0;" type="submit" name="reservieren" onclick="platzReservieren()" value="Reservieren">Reservieren</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using jquery.
Html button:

```
<button id="myBtn"></button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#myBtn").click(
function(){
$("#elementToChangeStyle").css("propertyname","value");
});
```

Also include jquery in head if you haven't yet,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a turorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
         .btn {
         height: 50%;
         margin: 1% 0 0 0;
         }
         .canvas-reservated {
         background-color: lightgreen;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary " type="submit" name="reservieren" value="Reservieren">Reservieren</button>
      <div class="row" id="courts">
         <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 1</h3>
            <canvas id="court1" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt1()"></canvas>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 2</h3>
            <canvas id="court2" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt2()"></canvas>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 3</h3>
            <canvas id="court3" class="canvas" width="300" height="350" onclick="leftClickOnCourt3()"></canvas>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         const btn = document.querySelector('button');
         
         btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
             var court1 = document.getElementById('court1');
             court1.classList.add('canvas-reservated');
         });
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```